# Execute function on button press (unity3d/C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Basically, what I'm trying to do is when pressing Z - it executes function to spin, and X - it executes function to stop spinning. Before, I had UI buttons which worked perfectly fine, now I try doing it by button but nothing happens.

Also, if you can suggest on how to make it start spinning and stop spinning by only pressing "Space" button, that'd be great.

Heres my code so far:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class spin : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 500f;
    public Button starter;
    public Button stopper;
    bool isSpinning = false;

    IEnumerator spinnerCoroutine;

    void Start()
    {
        //The spin function
        spinnerCoroutine = spinCOR();

        //Button btn = starter.GetComponent<Button>();
        //Button butn = stopper.GetComponent<Button>();

        //butn.onClick.AddListener(FidgetSpinnerStop);
        //btn.onClick.AddListener(FidgetSpinnerStart);


        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Z)) {

            FidgetSpinnerStart();
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.X)) {
            FidgetSpinnerStop();
        }
    }

    IEnumerator spinCOR()
    {
        //Spin forever untill FidgetSpinnerStop is called 
        while (true)
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            //Wait for the next frame
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    void FidgetSpinnerStart()
    {
        //Spin only if it is not spinning
        if (!isSpinning)
        {
            isSpinning = true;
            StartCoroutine(spinnerCoroutine);
        }
    }

    void FidgetSpinnerStop()
    {
        //Stop Spinning only if it is already spinning
        if (isSpinning)
        {
            StopCoroutine(spinnerCoroutine);
            isSpinning = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: The Fidget spinner trend is going too far......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are just two problems in your code:

**1**.Checking the keypress in the `Start()` function.

The `Start()` will be called once while the `Update()` function will be called every frame.

You need to use the `Update()` function to constantly poll the input every frame.

**2**.Using `Input.GetKey()` function to check for keypress.

The `Input.GetKey()` function can return true multiple times over several frames. While you may not see any problems now, that's because the `isSpinning` variable is preventing possible problems but you will run into problems if you want to add more code directly inside the `if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Z))` code because those code will execute multiple times in a frame.

You need to use the `Input.GetKeyDown()` function.

```
public class spin : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 500f;
    public Button starter;
    public Button stopper;
    bool isSpinning = false;

    IEnumerator spinnerCoroutine;

    void Start()
    {
        spinnerCoroutine = spinCOR();
    }

    void Update()
    {    
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z)) {

            FidgetSpinnerStart();
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X)) {
            FidgetSpinnerStop();
        }
    }

    IEnumerator spinCOR()
    {
        //Spin forever until FidgetSpinnerStop is called 
        while (true)
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            //Wait for the next frame
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    void FidgetSpinnerStart()
    {
        //Spin only if it is not spinning
        if (!isSpinning)
        {
            isSpinning = true;
            StartCoroutine(spinnerCoroutine);
        }
    }

    void FidgetSpinnerStop()
    {
        //Stop Spinning only if it is already spinning
        if (isSpinning)
        {
            StopCoroutine(spinnerCoroutine);
            isSpinning = false;
        }
    }
}
```

> Also, if you can suggest on how to make it start spinning and stop
>   spinning by only pressing "Space" button, that'd be great

You can do that with  `KeyCode.Space`. Check if Space key is pressed then check the `isSpinning` variable before starting/stopping the coroutine.

Just replace the `Update` function above with the one below:

```
void Update()
{
    //Start if Space-key is pressed AND is not Spinning
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && !isSpinning)
    {
        FidgetSpinnerStart();
    }

    //Stop if Space-key is pressed AND is already Spinning   
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isSpinning)
    {
        FidgetSpinnerStop();
    }
}
```

Comment: `Input.GetKey()` cannot return true multiple times per frame.

Comment: I don't know how to word that right. What I meant to say is that it will return `true` over **many** frames until it is released causing the code to execute several times. A single key press can cause that to run more than once.

Comment: That's the right wording. However, sometimes you want that behavior (automatic gun for example)

Comment: Yes, I [know](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/unity3d/3413/input-system#t=201707070831238238044) that but by reading OP's question that's not the behavior OP want.

Comment: It look like OP doesn't know what they want.

Comment: That's it. Exactly what I wanted and needed. Thanks for the tips. Forgot about Start() and Update() when doing that. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Your input logic is only executed once, when `Start()` is executed.

Put it in the `Update()` method to check for it every frame.

In this case remove the coroutine and put its logic (without the `while`-loop) into the `Update()` method aswell.

```
public class spin : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float speed = 500f;

    [SerializeField]
    private Button starter;

    [SerializeField]
    private Button stopper;

    [SerializeField]
    bool isSpinning = false;

    void Update()
    {    
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z))
        {
            isSpinning = true ;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X))
        {
            isSpinning = false ;
        }

        if( isSpinning )
        {
             transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, speed * Time.deltaTime)
        }
    }
}
```

[Further reading](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html)